# Do items like the Iron Armbands of Power modify the damage a Beastmaster Ranger's Animal Companion outputs on a Melee Basic Attack?

Tags: dnd-4e, ranger

Given a Beastmaster ranger (or multiclass feat which grants an animal companion) and, for the sake of argument, a cat companion.

Does a character's personal equipment which effects all melee attacks (like iron armbands of power) boost the damage of the companion's melee basic attacks?

Does a character's personal equipment effect powers like [Predator Strike](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=4369) which attack via the beast?

Is there a difference between the two cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, and typically no.

If the animal companion is making the attack it is a separate creature and uses it's own bonuses (as defined by the type and level of the creature plus any applicable temporary bonuses).

If the power in question does damage in the form of "1[B] + beast's Strength modifier" than it uses the beasts bonuses only and items like the Iron Armbands of Power would not be included.

Most Melee weapon (beast x) powers do damage from the beast, but there are exceptions like [Driving the Quarry](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/power.aspx?id=4375) which is based on the Ranger's attack.

Comment: I'm no longer as confident of my answer as I was when I wrote it.  I've been meaning to do more research, but haven't gotten around to it yet.  (My actual hope was that someone would post an alternate explanation so that the voters would have options)